# How to fix stan sampling getting stuck with inverse transformation of response variable

Tags: regression, inverse, r-package, stan, rstan

I'm using the R package `brms` to run extensive mixed-effects models (4000 observations, 99 fixed effects, 200 group levels) since `lme4` gives convergence errors for such large models.
I run these models using 4 chains, 8000 iterations and 2000 warmup samples. After running 4 to 5 hours, an brmsfit object is returned which I can then analyse.

During such an analysis I noticed the presence of heteroscedasticity looking at the plot of fitted values versus residual values. Experimentation on a smaller model (using the `lme4` package) showed that taking the inverse of the response variable (1/Y) solved this issue. I wanted to run the larger regression model using the `brms` package and the inverse transformation of Y, but the sampling seems to get stuck. After running for 20 hours, it stays at `iteration:  1/8000 [0%] (Warmup)` for every chain. I have tried to run it with `rstanarm`, but it gets stuck here as well. I also tried to specify `family=gaussian(link='inverse')` instead of 1/Y, but this did not resolve the issue.

Does anyone have an idea why the sampling gets stuck? 
Thanks in advance!

This is the stancode I use:

```
functions {
}   
data {        
  int<lower=1> N;  // number of observations       
  vector[N] Y;  // response variable   
  int<lower=1> K;  // number of fixed effects   
  matrix[N, K] X;  // FE design matrix  
  vector[K] X_means;  // column means of X   
  // data for random effects of problem   
  int<lower=1> J_1[N];  // RE levels   
  int<lower=1> N_1;  // number of levels   
  int<lower=1> K_1;  // number of REs   
  row_vector[K_1] Z_1[N];  // RE design matrix  
  int NC_1;  // number of correlations   
}   
transformed data {    
}   
parameters {   
    real temp_Intercept;  // temporary Intercept   
  vector[K] b;  // fixed effects 
  matrix[N_1, K_1] pre_1;  // unscaled REs 
  vector<lower=0>[K_1] sd_1;  // RE standard deviation 
  // cholesky factor of correlation matrix 
  cholesky_factor_corr[K_1] L_1;  real<lower=0> sigma;  // residual SD 
} 
transformed parameters { 
  vector[N] eta;  // linear predictor   
  vector[K_1] r_1[N_1];  // REs   
  // compute linear predictor   
  eta <- X * b + temp_Intercept;   
  for (i in 1:N_1) {   
    r_1[i] <- sd_1 .* (L_1 * to_vector(pre_1[i]));  // scale REs   
  }   
  for (n in 1:N) {   
    eta[n] <- (eta[n] + Z_1[n] * r_1[J_1[n]]);   
  }   
}   
model {   
  // prior specifications   
  sd_1 ~ student_t(3, 0, 16381);   
  L_1 ~ lkj_corr_cholesky(1);   
  to_vector(pre_1) ~ normal(0, 1);   
  sigma ~ student_t(3, 0, 16381);   
  // likelihood contribution   
  Y_inv ~ normal(eta, sigma);   
}   
generated quantities {   
  real b_Intercept;  // fixed effects intercept   
  corr_matrix[K_1] Cor_1;   
  vector<lower=-1,upper=1>[NC_1] cor_1;   
  b_Intercept <- temp_Intercept - dot_product(X_means, b);   
  // take only relevant parts of correlation matrix   
  Cor_1 <- multiply_lower_tri_self_transpose(L_1);   
  cor_1[1] <- Cor_1[1,2];   
  cor_1[2] <- Cor_1[1,3];     
  cor_1[3] <- Cor_1[2,3];   
  cor_1[4] <- Cor_1[1,4];   
  cor_1[5] <- Cor_1[2,4];   
  cor_1[6] <- Cor_1[3,4];   
  cor_1[7] <- Cor_1[1,5];   
  cor_1[8] <- Cor_1[2,5];   
  cor_1[9] <- Cor_1[3,5];   
  cor_1[10] <- Cor_1[4,5];   
  cor_1[11] <- Cor_1[1,6];   
  cor_1[12] <- Cor_1[2,6];   
  cor_1[13] <- Cor_1[3,6];   
  cor_1[14] <- Cor_1[4,6];   
  cor_1[15] <- Cor_1[5,6];   
  cor_1[16] <- Cor_1[1,7];   
  cor_1[17] <- Cor_1[2,7];   
  cor_1[18] <- Cor_1[3,7];   
  cor_1[19] <- Cor_1[4,7];   
  cor_1[20] <- Cor_1[5,7];   
  cor_1[21] <- Cor_1[6,7];   
  cor_1[22] <- Cor_1[1,8];   
  cor_1[23] <- Cor_1[2,8];   
  cor_1[24] <- Cor_1[3,8];   
  cor_1[25] <- Cor_1[4,8];   
  cor_1[26] <- Cor_1[5,8];   
  cor_1[27] <- Cor_1[6,8];   
  cor_1[28] <- Cor_1[7,8];   
  cor_1[29] <- Cor_1[1,9];   
  cor_1[30] <- Cor_1[2,9];   
  cor_1[31] <- Cor_1[3,9];   
  cor_1[32] <- Cor_1[4,9];   
  cor_1[33] <- Cor_1[5,9];   
  cor_1[34] <- Cor_1[6,9];   
  cor_1[35] <- Cor_1[7,9];   
  cor_1[36] <- Cor_1[8,9];   
  cor_1[37] <- Cor_1[1,10];   
  cor_1[38] <- Cor_1[2,10];   
  cor_1[39] <- Cor_1[3,10];   
  cor_1[40] <- Cor_1[4,10];   
  cor_1[41] <- Cor_1[5,10];   
  cor_1[42] <- Cor_1[6,10];  
  cor_1[43] <- Cor_1[7,10];   
  cor_1[44] <- Cor_1[8,10];   
  cor_1[45] <- Cor_1[9,10];   
  cor_1[46] <- Cor_1[1,11];   
  cor_1[47] <- Cor_1[2,11];   
  cor_1[48] <- Cor_1[3,11];   
  cor_1[49] <- Cor_1[4,11];   
  cor_1[50] <- Cor_1[5,11];   
  cor_1[51] <- Cor_1[6,11];   
  cor_1[52] <- Cor_1[7,11];   
  cor_1[53] <- Cor_1[8,11];   
  cor_1[54] <- Cor_1[9,11];   
  cor_1[55] <- Cor_1[10,11];     
  cor_1[56] <- Cor_1[1,12];   
  cor_1[57] <- Cor_1[2,12];   
  cor_1[58] <- Cor_1[3,12];   
  cor_1[59] <- Cor_1[4,12];   
  cor_1[60] <- Cor_1[5,12];   
  cor_1[61] <- Cor_1[6,12];   
  cor_1[62] <- Cor_1[7,12];   
  cor_1[63] <- Cor_1[8,12];   
  cor_1[64] <- Cor_1[9,12];   
  cor_1[65] <- Cor_1[10,12];   
  cor_1[66] <- Cor_1[11,12];   
  cor_1[67] <- Cor_1[1,13];   
  cor_1[68] <- Cor_1[2,13];   
  cor_1[69] <- Cor_1[3,13];   
  cor_1[70] <- Cor_1[4,13];   
  cor_1[71] <- Cor_1[5,13];   
  cor_1[72] <- Cor_1[6,13];   
  cor_1[73] <- Cor_1[7,13];   
  cor_1[74] <- Cor_1[8,13];   
  cor_1[75] <- Cor_1[9,13];   
  cor_1[76] <- Cor_1[10,13];   
  cor_1[77] <- Cor_1[11,13];   
  cor_1[78] <- Cor_1[12,13];   
}
```

Comment: I would suggest that you try the `QR = TRUE` argument to `stan_lmer`, either with `1/y` or the inverse link function to the `gaussian` family. Also, the default number of warmup and samples should be more than enough for a viable Stan program and increasing them to 2000 and 8000 probably won't help with a non-viable Stan program.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately it did not fix the sampling issue, neither using `1/y` nor the inverse link function to the `gaussian` family.

Comment: I tried running the model with `1/y` (and with `QR=FALSE`) for 120 hours (5 days) and now the sampling has reached 25%, so the model does work, it just needs a really long time. Is there a way of speeding up the sampling process?

Comment: Did you try with `QR = TRUE`?

Comment: The experiment with 120 hours I started before posting my question here, so in this experiment I did **not** specify `QR=TRUE`. I tried  `QR=TRUE` both with `1/y` and the inverse link function to the `gaussian` family with a runtime of 12 hours after you suggested it. I saw no improvement in the sampling however.